# Should repositories be atomic?

Tags: c#, sql, repository-pattern, .net-core, solid-principles

I am designing my repositories and I have a doubt. For example when creating a new User, I have to add entries on different tables. Right now I use something like:

```
public User CreateNewUser()
{
    try
    {
        using (var con = new SqlConnection(_SecureConnectionString))
        {
            con.Open();

            using (var transaction = con.BeginTransaction())
            {
               User user = //User Repository query to INSERT the user on dbo.Users and return object

               user.Items = // Item Repository query to INSERT on dbo.Items that have a FK to dbo.Users
               user.Whatever = // Whatever repository call to INSERT on tables that are related to the new user

               transaction.Commit();
            }
        }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        transaction.Rollback();
        throw;
    }
}
```

My question is, if creating a new user and it always have to create entries on different tables managed by other repositories, should I avoid being so atomic and do it on a single query on the UserRepository even if it insert on other tables? I am doing 3 database hits when I could do it on a single one.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using entity framework?

Comment: As commented to Zoran, this is part of a game server solution, Entity framework is poor in speed compared to  dapper. For this specific case (creating the user on registration) I don't need to be fast but is not always the case.

Comment: You are missing a unit of work which will coordinates the transaction across repositories.

Answer (score 0):

If you are relying on EF `DbContext` as repository, then my answer to the question is yes, you should use `DbContext` at hand to insert all new objects. In that way,the context would control the database transaction and all INSERTs would be done within a single transaction when you save changes.

And, as you have already observed, that leads to a slight complication. Some entities would exist in more than one `DbContext`, unless you are building one giant context for entire schema or database.

EF has improved its support for contexts that share some entities, so from syntactical point of view you should be fine nowadays. The problem will then be the confusion, since one entity appears in more than one context.

Another approach, which I am using very often in recent time, is to apply DDD techniques and organize your entities into well defined groups, named aggregates. In that case, one entity would appear in exactly one context. But then you would have to use more than one context in some operations. That will also require you to share the connection and transaction between contexts, which all together adds a lot of complexity to the solution.

Comment: Thanks for your response!, I am working on a game server built in .Net Core (that's why I don't have a TransactionScope... yet ;) ),  I decided to go for dapper due to the query speed performance. I am not sure if dapper can do contexts like EF.

Comment: No, with Dapper you would construct your own repositories. That makes it even easier to use the same entities in more than one repository, since it's all your responsibility how you're persisting them.